# Convert non-integer number to time period (years/months/days etc.)

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

How to convert a non-integer number (e.g. 3.5 or 2.567893) to a time period/duration such as years?

The following only works for integer number:

```
library(lubridate)

years(3) # works    
years(3.5) # doesn't work
years(2.567893) # doesn't work
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-integers periods of years don't make sense, since half a calendar year is ambiguous.  You can have non-integer durations of years though:

```
dyears(3.5) #OK
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Actually, I meant "durations". I added this to my question.